# How do I keep images zoomed at the same level when viewing multiple images in one session?

Tags: windows-7, images, zoom

I have a lot of images of the same size (2272x1920), each depicting a layer in a model. The interesting part of the images is a rectangular area that is of the same size and at the same position in all of the images, so I zoom in on the interesting part. However when I go to the next image the image is again zoomed out to normal. I want to view the images in series with the image fixed at the given zoom level and position.

How can i achive this?

I've tried the standard image viewer built into Windows 7, and also IrfanView. Solutions to these two programs are very welcome as these are the ones I use regularly, but also solutions for other programs are welcome.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This can be achieved in IrfanView:

1. Open the first image.
2. Zoom to the desired level and position.
3. On the IrfanView menu bar, select `View->Lock Zoom (Shift+L)` and `View->Keep Scroll position`
4. Browse other images.

Comment: belated thank you, I wanted a similar ability and am now using irfanview.  Though I now need to figure out how to configure it so it scrolls down faster when I use the mouse wheel, but now that I know the program sure I can google that :)

Comment: _Zoom to the desired level and position._ Well how can I do that?? Eg how to zoom to 200% 300% etc? All I get are level that make the pixels show a moiree.. belated tia

Answer (score 4):

[Adobe Lightroom](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshoplightroom/) supports the behaviour you are asking for but it's not free.

Another option would be to make temporary copies cropped to the area of interest, if you have the disk space are comfortable working in the Command Prompt. [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) (free) could do this for you:

```
for %i in (src\*.jpg) do convert "%i" -crop 800x600+200+200 -resize "200%" "dest\%~ni.png"
```

The above example would take each JPG image in the *src* folder, grab an 800x600 section 200 pixels from the top left, magnify it by 200% and save it as a PNG in the *dest* folder.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [Fastone Image viewer](https://www.faststone.org/download.htm)

1. Open image in windowed or fullscreen view
2. Go to `Settings` (F12), and then the `Viewer` tab
3. Uncheck `Reset image position to (0,0) when loading images`
4. At right, in `Auto Image Size` dropdown choose `Lock zoom ratio`
5. Pan and zoom as desired; use `PageUp` and `PageDown` to switch between images

[Here is video demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1utJr.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Irfanview is not free for commercial use. However Microsoft Windows Office Picture Manager can be used to achieve the task, and it is free for personal and commercial use. It may also be installed without owning Microsoft Office despite the "Office" association.

**Steps**

1. Open the photo with Microsoft Office Picture Manager 2007 or 2010
2. Zoom to the desired level
3. Use the small triangle direction keys at the base of the window to go to the next image. Arrow keys will only move the zoomed in image in their particular directions.

**Obtaining Microsoft Office Picture Manager**

If you do not have Microsoft Office, Microsoft Office Picture Manager 2007 or 2010 may be downloaded and installed seperately through the free Sharepoint 2007 or Sharepoint 2010 installers. During the installation, select only Office Picture Manager for installation (if you do not want Sharepoint Designer installed).
Sharepoint Designer 2010 32-bit link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=16573